# JavaFX - Opening & Running Jar from another Jar in Different Directory not Getting Correct Home Directory

Tags: java, javafx, jar, executable-jar

In my application I have the requirement to call/run JarB as an executable jar from JarA. They are in two different directories. JarA knows where jarB is, and I have no problem getting JarA to run JarB. However, when JarB runs, it is seeing JarA's home directory as it's home directory rather than the directory it (JarB) is actually in. As a result, JarB is not finding needed support files.

Here is how I am calling JarB from JarA.  Again, this works fine as far as launching it.

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java --module-path " + path + "lib/ " +
                    "--add-modules javafx.controls -jar " + path + "JarB.jar");
```

Is there a parameter/setting I can change or a different way to call JarB that will cause it to use it's own home directory? THANKS!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ProcessBuilder` and set the directory:

```
Process proc = new ProcessBuilder("java ",
        "--module-path ",
        path + "lib/ ",
        "--add-modules",
        "javafx.controls",
        "-jar ",
        path + "JarB.jar")
    .directory(new File("/path/to/working/directory"))
    .start();
```

Typically, though, this shouldn't be necessary. An executable jar file should either *contain* it's own static resources (in which case you load them as resources, not as files), or, for non-static resources (i.e. ones that the user might edit, or might be updated by the application) they would be stored in a specific location, independent of the jar file.